# Find if value in nested sublist is greater than X within Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas, nested-lists

dataframe:

```
col1
[[0.43], [0.46], [1.0], [0.323]]
[[0.33], [0.66], [1.0], [0.3412]]
[[0.27], [0.42], [0.13], [0.332]]
```

I'm trying to create a column based on: if there's a number in the nested list of `col11` >= .5 then "yes" else "no".

Result:

```
col1                                col2
[[0.43], [0.46], [1.0], [0.323]]    yes
[[0.33], [0.66], [1.0], [0.3412]]   yes
[[0.27], [0.42], [0.13], [0.332]]   no
```

It would also be good to have a column with the location of where the number was in nested list that was >= .5. for the above df, this would be `col3: 3,3,N/A`

Thinking something like this:

```
for i in df.col1:
    print(i)
    if j in i >= .05:
        print(i,"yes")
    else:
        print(i,"no")
```

Comment: I could change this column of nested lists to just lists.. Not sure how to do that. looking it up now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `apply` should do

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: max(e[0] for e in x) > 0.5)
```

Output

```
                                col1   col2
0   [[0.43], [0.46], [1.0], [0.323]]   True
1  [[0.33], [0.66], [1.0], [0.3412]]   True
2  [[0.27], [0.42], [0.13], [0.332]]  False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
sub_df = df[pd.DataFrame(df['col1'].apply(lambda x : sum(x,[])).tolist()).ge(0.5).any(1).values]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension with `any`. `any` is faster than `max` due it short-circuits on `True`

```
df['col2'] =  [any(y[0] >= 0.5 for y in x) for x in df.col1]

Out[1815]:
                                col1   col2
0   [[0.43], [0.46], [1.0], [0.323]]   True
1  [[0.33], [0.66], [1.0], [0.3412]]   True
2  [[0.27], [0.42], [0.13], [0.332]]  False
```

---

**Some timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True)

In [1820]: %timeit  [any(y[0] >= 0.5 for y in x) for x in df.col1]
41.2 ms ± 1.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [1823]: %timeit df['col1'].apply(lambda x: max(e[0] for e in x) >= 0.5)
51.9 ms ± 1.58 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

side-test list comprehension with `max`

```
In [1827]: %timeit [max(y[0] for y in x) >= 0.5 for x in df.col1]
49.9 ms ± 2.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So, `any` is faster although not significant.